# Pass Data From Stripe To Joomla

Tags: joomla, stripe-payments

Using RSFormsPro and Stripe when someone has already created an account on my site and purchased something, can I return the last 4 of the card used to purchase the item from Stripe and populate that on my Joomla site asking the user if they want to use this card?

Comment: You should be able to retrieve https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-last4 and use that in your own system.

Comment: Oh wow, so the payment method object has card.lastfour - this looks like i'd have to modify some config files, right?  Or could I plug it in in the Javascript section of my form properties?

Comment: @Hot If you are doing Joomla development, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  When you have Joomla questions, please ask them in the dedicated community.